# Can I add multiple clipboards to the right click copy command?

Tags: windows-registry, copy-paste, regedit

I find myself copying text from multiple locations and pasting them into one location at work. Every time I'd select and copy I'd have to navigate to the final destination to paste, then back to some other document to pull another set of of data to bring it over to the new document and then back and forth and back and forth. I was hoping to have multiple copy options in the right click menu. Like:

Copy(1) 
Copy(2) 
Copy(3)

Paste(1) 
Paste(2) 
Paste(3)

I think anything more than three would be overkill.
I've added things like 'Defrag', 'CMD from here', and 'Take Ownership' to my right click menu by creating or modifying registry keys. I was hoping there was an edit to the registry I could do to add this function.

Thanks.

Comment: [Store Multiple Items to Clipboard in Windows](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/19420/store-multiple-items-to-clipboard-in-windows/)

Comment: I saw that while doing some research, and I had a chance to give it a try. The program adds another whole window I'd have to click to in order to add a copy to the clipboard, If anything it's adding a step.  (in my opinion) If it could be tucked away inside the right click menu then it would be perfect. Thank you for your suggestion though!